# build.gradle dependancies for retrofit and latest version of okhttp

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

In our application we use retrofit for networking with the following dependancies:

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

Of late we started getting this [crash](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3308) which has been resolved. How then do i fix this within our app?
My understanding is that retrofit is built on top of the okHttp library.
So does this mean we would have to wait for a new version of retrofit that includes the new okHttp version OR I can manually include the new version of okHttp as a seperate dependancy and end up with:

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
```

Proguard config is (only the retrofit part though)

```
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclasseswithmembers class * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembers interface * { @retrofit2.* <methods>; }
-dontwarn okio.**
```

Comment: The dependencies that you've included already contain the `okhttp` library. Most probably, Your proguard file is not correct. Can you paste it here?

Comment: it's about the okhttp lib and it's fixed at the 3.8.1 version just add it to your gradle

Comment: @OussemaAroua if I'm understanding correctly when i include retrofit it already comes with inbuilt okHttp which might be version 3.8.0 for example. Wont including 3.8.1 manually cause conflicts/problems.

Comment: @AndroidNoob like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can force new okhttp version by adding `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'`

If you run `gradlew app:dependencies`, you will see this:

```
releaseCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: release
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0 -> 3.8.1
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0
```

It is means, that Retrofit declare dependency `okhttp:3.8.0`, but Gradle replace it by `okhttp:3.8.1`

PS: This is applied for situation, when you does not define custom dependency resolution strategy

Answer (score 0):

Add this two and try

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
```

Comment: The crash i'm interested in was fixed in 3.8.1.

Comment: I am using this 2.0.0

Answer (score -1):

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
```

Comment: Textual comments needed!

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, it would help others reading your answer if you gave some comments/explanation as what your doing and why.